# How to deduct equations of speed and acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems

I´ve been trying a new topic that consist in deduct  equations that allow to know the speed and acceleration vectors in a given point for differents coordinate systems (rectangular; cylindrical; intrinsical) from a particle that follows the next trajectories:

$$y=ax+b$$$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$$$y=a\sqrt{x}+c$$$$y=\frac{x}{b+x}+c$$$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$$$r=r_0 e^{a\theta}$$$$y=a.sen(bx)$$
I really don´t understand... help.

What book is suggested to understand the topic?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulae as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read An Introduction to Mechanics by Daniel Kleppner, this is an excellent book where explains vectors in different coordinates. Basically, you  should convert your cartesian components in curvilinear coordinates and then use the relations (You must know how derive them) to velocity and acceleration, for example, for velocity in cylindrical coordinates.
\begin{align}
v_{\rho}=& H_\rho \dot{\rho} = \dot{\rho}\\
v_{\varphi}=& H_z \dot{\varphi}= \rho \dot{\varphi}\\
v_{z}=& H_z \dot{z}= \dot{z}\\
\end{align}

where $ H_\rho ,  H_\varepsilon, H_z$ are metric coefficients.

Also, you should read http://edshare.soton.ac.uk/2354/1/MA215ex6qu1.pdf or see https://www.coursera.org/lecture/dynamics/module-4-rectangular-cartesian-coordinate-system-cylindrical-coordinate-system-FQMpG